# Could not load program iperf3 after install on AIX 7.1 Server

Tags: software-installation, aix, libraries

I don't seem to find any solution to my AIX related problem when attempting to use iperf3 after install:

```
root@dxxxxxxx in /: iperf3 -s
Could not load program iperf3:
Could not load module /opt/freeware/lib64/libiperf.a(libiperf.so.0).
        Dependent module libgcc_s.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
Could not load module libgcc_s.a(shr.o).
System error: No such file or directory
Could not load module iperf3_64.
        Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib64/libiperf.a(libiperf.so.0) could not be loaded.
Could not load module .
```

I checked /opt/freeware/lib64 and see the file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     system       316155 Sep 18 2017  libiperf.a
```

but it does not show the libiperf.so.0 content when I do a:

```
/opt/freeware/lib64# ar -vt libipef.a
```

Also, I am missing libgcc_s.a(shr.o) file.

Comment: I assume you meant `ar -vt libiperf.a` (with an typo/missing "r")?

Comment: I assume (?) you downloaded the iperf RPM(s)? from the IBM AIX Toolbox for Linux site, https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/ ?

Comment: sorry, yes, that was a typo on libiperf.a and yes, I downloaded iperf3.2 from IBM site.

Comment: What steps did you take to install iperf? The RPM file should have installed `/opt/freeware/lib64/libiperf.a`.

Comment: I downloaded iperf 3.2 from https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html#I

Comment: reposting:   1) I downloaded iperf 3.2 from https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html#I  2) rpm -i iperf3-3.2-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm.   It did create /optfreeware/lib64/libiperf.a     ... when I do a # ar -vt libiperf.a I thought I would see some content (libiperf.so.0) but the command retuns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iperf3 RPM installs links in /usr/lib to the /opt/freeware/lib directories for the libiperf.a files, so as long as your `LIBPATH` contains the `/usr/lib` directory, it should pick up the libiperf library. LIBPATH is commonly set in `/etc/environment`, so if you haven't set it, you'll need to manually set it until you can edit that file and reboot.

The libgcc_s.a file is provided by the `libgcc` RPM file at the same site; download the version for your OS level (6.1, 7.1, or 7.2).

Comment: Jeff Schaller, thank you very much for your help. I had neglected to install libgcc. Since yesterday I removed iperf3 thinking maybe I had downloaded a bad rpm, today after your suggestion, I installed libgcc, re-installed iperf3 and now it is working. Thank you again!